# Download multiple videos at the same time in the iCloud Drive iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

I copied some video files to a folder in iCloud and when I opened the iCloud Drive app on my iPhone and selected a file, it started downloading. But if I went back and selected the file again, the download started from scratch. So if I have 100 movies, I have to select a file, wait for it to download and select the next one, and so forth. I searched for an option to download offline all the files but couldn't find one.

Comment: What's the size of iCloud files online and how does that compare with the storage space on your iPhone?

Comment: Hundreds of MB, and my phone has 128 GB storage.

Comment: Cool - I've seen people with 50 GB of iCloud other documents and 8 GB iPhones so clearly that won't work. It seems odd that 100 movies would be only hundreds of MB though.

Comment: I estimated, can't check right now, the thing is that I do have enough space

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a way to download multiple file at the same time with iCloud Drive. 
But you can maybe solve the problem with AirDrop. If you have multiple files, for example in Finder on your Mac selected, you can send them all with only one click to your iPhone. The same works also from iOS-Device to iOS-Device.
[image: The transmission should look somehow like this.]

Comment: Wouldn't them end up in the Photos library among my photos?

Comment: That is correct, but if you have a compatible app that can open videos out of your Photos library, you can open the Videos with that app. Alternatively, you could synchronize your iPhone directly via iTunes to your Movie app or under the app category in iTunes to your desired app.